# SSRS: Report Item Lines Disappearing / Partially Showing

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, reportbuilder3.0, diagonal

I'm creating a new SSRS report with Report Builder for SQL Server 2012. Most things work well except for simple rendering of report item diagonal lines. I have attempted several times with the order of creation, "Bring to Front", "Bring Forward" etc. The result remains same. Part of the line is missing from the report on view as shown in the images below.

Design Mode View

[image]

Final View

[image]

Please tell me how to get the output to view like in design through "Save as PDF" renders good even thought the diagonal lines show partially. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried setting the background of the top textbox with the line across it to transparent / No color rather than white?

Comment: Hey Harry. Those are just report item lines too. Still waiting to add textboxes...

Comment: Strange.. I've done exactly what you have done and my preview looks fine.. just like the design mode view. Can you show your whole design window?

Comment: [Harry] Well... it views fine in Run mode. When running directly on Report Server (SQL Server Reporting Services), I get the odd look. Stackoverflow, has banned me from posting anymore images... Sorry.

Comment: Does it look OK when you export the report to say.. pdf?? If yes.. perhaps just a rendering issue...

Comment: I have accepted Report Builder 3.0 SQL Server 2012 "Run" mode and viewing on Report Server will render different results even though its Microsoft. The PDF exports properly (in this case). "Run" mode displays properly... so I will free myself from worrying about why this is. They will invent something else to use and SSRS will be gone on to glory... Hallelujah!